# How to solve a system of ODEs with scipy.integrate.odeint with a time-dependent variable

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am using the Zombie Apocalypse [example](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Zombie_Apocalypse_ODEINT.html) in the scipy cookbook to learn about solving systems of ODEs in python.

Within this model, there is an equation that provides the human population at each day, based on birth rate, death rate, and initial population.  based on the human population it then calculates how many zombies are created and killed.

I am interested in replacing the human population differential equation with a list of data that tells us the human population at each timestep. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Which, as people have pointed out, is because it does not make sense to multiply individual numbers by a list. I am not sure how to supply a number from the list at each time T to the differential equations.

Here is the code for two attempts

```
# solve the system dy/dt = f(y, t)
def f(y, t):
    Si = [345, 299, 933, 444, 265, 322] # replaced an equation with list
    Zi = y[0]
    Ri = y[1]
    # the model equations (see Munz et al. 2009)
    f0 = B*Si*Zi + G*Ri - A*Si*Zi
    f1 = d*Si + A*Si*Zi - G*Ri
    return [f0, f1]
```

I have also tried

```
numbers = [345, 299, 933, 444, 265, 322]
for t in [0, 5]:
    Si = numbers

# solve the system dy/dt = f(y, t)
def f(y, t):

    Zi = y[0]
    Ri = y[1]
    # the model equations (see Munz et al. 2009)
    f0 = B*Si*Zi + G*Ri - A*Si*Zi
    f1 = d*Si + A*Si*Zi - G*Ri
    return [f0, f1]
```

both attempts have the same problem of supplying the whole list to `f0` and `f1` instead of iteratively supplying 1 number from the list.

Comment: for a real life problem i am doing i need to replace 1 differential equation in a system with a list of real data.

i have also tried to define Si outside of the Y function defintion, but get the same error
 
    `code`numbers = [345, 299, 933, 444, 265, 322]
    `code`for t in [0, 5]:
     `code`     Si = numbers

Comment: Instead of talking about replacing a differential equation with a list of numbers (which does not make sense to me), try explaining the problem from the beginning, in terms of the information that you have.  For example, something like "I have a list of numbers.  The meaning of these numbers is [...].  I want to model a process in which these numbers are used to [...]"

Comment: you are correct i have phrased my question in a particularly dumb way, and i apologize. I do understand your point and pythons error, that i cant multiply my number by a list. I am trying to understand how to supply to to the f0 and f1 equations an item in the list at every timestep t.

thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: i am not clearly articulating what i am attempting to do. I am a biologist, and i have a symple system of ODEs, that models how a protein gets activated and then interacts with several other proteins. I now have real data about activated protein levels over a given timespan, i want to replace the equation that represents the activation of that protein in my model with the real timeseries data. 

in the zombie apocalypse model analogy, i would like to replace the equation that describes human population with respect to birth and death rates, with a list of human pop at different timepoints.

Comment: I have edited the question title and question. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would leave the equation for `Si` in and then fit the data. Is that an option for you?

Comment: it is not an option my data is just too noisy to be even worth it. At this point i think i need to not use Odeint or any solver and instead use a for loop to do this manually

Comment: @BobbyM: I still think it is possible despite the noise. I added an example below on how it can be approached. Let me know whether that suits you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understood from the comments below your question, you try to incorporate measured data that can be noisy. Rather than plugging the data in directly, you can use these data to fit your time-courses. Here I show the outcome for your variable `S`:

[image]

The `green dots` are sampled from the solution of the ODE system you provided. To mimic measurement errors, I added some noise to those data (`blue dots`). Then you can fit your ODE system to reproduce these data as good as possible (`red line`).

For these tasks you can use [`lmfit`](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/). The code that reproduces the plot looks like this (some explanation can be found in the inline comments):

```
# zombie apocalypse modeling
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit
from scipy.integrate import odeint


# solve the system dy/dt = f(y, t)
def f(y, t, paras):

    Si = y[0]
    Zi = y[1]
    Ri = y[2]

    try:
        P = paras['P'].value
        d = paras['d'].value
        B = paras['B'].value
        G = paras['G'].value
        A = paras['A'].value

    except:
        P, d, B, G, A = paras
    # the model equations (see Munz et al. 2009)
    f0 = P - B * Si * Zi - d * Si
    f1 = B * Si * Zi + G * Ri - A * Si * Zi
    f2 = d * Si + A * Si * Zi - G * Ri
    return [f0, f1, f2]


def g(t, x0, paras):
    """
    Solution to the ODE x'(t) = f(t,x,p) with initial condition x(0) = x0
    """
    x = odeint(f, x0, t, args=(paras,))
    return x


def residual(paras, t, data):
    x0 = paras['S0'].value, paras['Z0'].value, paras['R0'].value
    model = g(t, x0, paras)
    s_model = model[:, 0]
    return (s_model - data).ravel()

# just for reproducibility reasons
np.random.seed(1)

# initial conditions
S0 = 500.              # initial population
Z0 = 0                 # initial zombie population
R0 = 0                 # initial death population
y0 = [S0, Z0, R0]     # initial condition vector
t = np.linspace(0, 5., 100)         # time grid

P = 12      # birth rate
d = 0.0001  # natural death percent (per day)
B = 0.0095  # transmission percent  (per day)
G = 0.0001  # resurect percent (per day)
A = 0.0001  # destroy percent  (per day)

# solve the DEs
soln = odeint(f, y0, t, args=((P, d, B, G, A), ))
S = soln[:, 0]
Z = soln[:, 1]
R = soln[:, 2]

# plot results
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, S, label='Living')
plt.plot(t, Z, label='Zombies')
plt.xlabel('Days from outbreak')
plt.ylabel('Population')
plt.title('Zombie Apocalypse - No Init. Dead Pop.; No New Births.')
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()

# generate fake data
S_real = S[0::8]
S_measured = S_real + np.random.randn(len(S_real)) * 100
t_measured = t[0::8]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t_measured, S_real, 'o', color='g', label='real data')

# add some noise to your data to mimic measurement erros
plt.plot(t_measured, S_measured, 'o', color='b', label='noisy data')

# set parameters including bounds; you can also fix parameters (use vary=False)
params = Parameters()
params.add('S0', value=S0, min=490., max=510.)
params.add('Z0', value=Z0, vary=False)
params.add('R0', value=R0, vary=False)
params.add('P', value=10, min=8., max=12.)
params.add('d', value=0.0005, min=0.00001, max=0.005)
params.add('B', value=0.01, min=0.00001, max=0.01)
params.add('G', value=G, vary=False)
params.add('A', value=0.0005, min=0.00001, max=0.001)

# fit model
result = minimize(residual, params, args=(t_measured, S_measured), method='leastsq')  # leastsq nelder
# check results of the fit
data_fitted = g(t, y0, result.params)

plt.plot(t, data_fitted[:, 0], '-', linewidth=2, color='red', label='fitted data')
plt.legend()
# display fitted statistics
report_fit(result)

plt.show()
```

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to make this response. I will study it & I'm sure i will learn a lot. 

I should have been more clear about my hesitation (i am learning that coding and even talking about coding requires great precision). the fact that both your green dots and blue dots result in a similar fit equation is the problem. My goal is to find the relative contribution of each step in a biological process to the noise in the output. By forcing real data to the  model, I hoped to see how much noise it generates in the final output. I might need to rethink my approach

Comment: @BobbyM: The green dots were not used for the fit. They represent the "real" data i.e. the data without any measurement error. In real life, this is not realistic, you will always have measurement errors, biological variation (gene expression is stochastic). To mimic that, I added noise to the real data which is represented by the blue dots. The red line is generated by ONLY taking the blue dots into account i.e. the measured data. As one can see, despite the noise, one can reproduce the real data very well. And that is what we always do in biology: deal with noise :)

Comment: @BobbyM: How is the study going? Any questions about the code above? Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Hi, Sorry that I have not replied earlier, I was not working on this problem last week (lots of midterm grading).  I now understand your solution and the code works well. Your comment about the measurement error has given me a lot to think about. Although i think about measurement error frequently when looking at experimental data, it had never occurred to me that it needs to be considered during modeling as well. I am still grappling with what is the best approach. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can not know a-priori at what points the numerical integrator evaluates the ODE function. The integrator (`odeint` and others that are not explicitly "fixed step-size") generates dynamically an internal list of points which may have a smaller or sometimes also larger step-size than the given list of sampling points. The values for the output are interpolated from the internal list.

If you want to replace a part of the ODE with a function, then you have to transform your sample data into a function. This can be done via interpolation. Use the [scipy.interpolate.interp1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) function to generate function objects that you then can use like any other scalar function.

Comment: thank you for your answer it was clear and easy to understand. unfortunately interporlate will not work for me, my data is very noisy, its basically a cloud. is there an alternative to odeint that may use a fixed step size? if not do i need to use a loop to explicity specify a step size of 1?

Comment: @BobbyM: The noise does not really matter; you can still try to fit your data (I added code below).

Answer (score 0):

to specifically do what i was asking in the question, which is use values in place of one of hte ODES you will need to use a loop in which you use the odesolver to solve your system for 1 second, and then take the outputs as the initial conditions for the next iteration of the loop. The code for this approach is below. However as many have pointed out, in most situations it will be better to use interpolate as described by Cleb and others

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

Si = [345, 299, 933, 444, 265, 322] # replaced an equation with list

#Parameters
P = 0           # birth rate
d = 0.0001  # natural death percent (per day)
B = 0.0095  # transmission percent  (per day)
G = 0.0001  # resurect percent (per day)
A = 0.0001  # destroy percent  (per day)

# solve the system dy/dt = f(y, t)
def f(y, t):
    Zi = y[0]
    Ri = y[1]
    # the model equations (see Munz et al. 2009)
    f0 = B*Si*Zi + G*Ri - A*Si*Zi
    f1 = d*Si + A*Si*Zi - G*Ri
    return [f0, f1]

# initial conditions
Z0 = 0                      # initial zombie population
R0 = 0                      # initial death population
y0 = [Z0, R0]   # initial condition vector
# a timestep of 1 forces the odesolve to use your inputs at the beginning and provide outputs at the end of the timestep. 
# In this way the problem that LutzL has described is avoided.
t  = np.linspace(0, 1, 2)       
Si =np.array(Si).T

#create a space for storing your outputdata
dataZ =[]
dataR =[]
#use a for loop to use your custom inputs for Si
for Si in Si:
    y0 = [Z0, R0]
    soln = odeint(f, y0, t)
    Z = soln[:, 0]
    R = soln[:, 1]
    #define your outputs as the initial conditions for the next iteration of the loop
    Z_0 = Z[1]
    R_0 = R[1]
    #store your outputs 
    dataZ.append(Z[1])
    dataR.append(R[1])


print (dataZ)
print (dataR)
```